# A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: vb.net

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember.

Comment: Your question is inadequate. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That includes the relevant code and a description of exactly what you're trying to achieve, how and what data is in use at the time. I can tell what's causing this specific issue but, without more details, I have to guess at the best solution. On other occasions, not even that much may be possible. Please spend some time in the Help Center for the site and learn how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that you cannot set the `SelectedValue` property if you haven't set the `ValueMember` property. The `ValueMember` is the name of the property or column from the `DataSource` whose value you want exposed via the `SelectedValue`. For instance, if you bind a list of items that have `Name` and `Id` properties, you might bind like this:

```
With myComboBoxOrListBox
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "Id"
    .DataSource = myListOfItems
End With
```

The user will then see the `Name` values listed in the control and, when they select one, you can get the corresponding `Id` value from the `SelectedValue`. You can also assign an `Id` value to the `SelectedValue` property and the corresponding `Name` will be selected in the list.

If you're not binding or the items in the list are simple types like `String` or `Integer` then you should not be setting the `SelectedValue` property to select an item programmatically. Instead, set the `SelectedItem` property.